# How can I access the output of a bazel rule from another rule without using a relative path?

Tags: bazel, dhall

I am attempting to use Bazel to compile a dhall program based on dhall-kubernetes to generate a Kubernetes YAML file.

The [basic dhall compile](https://github.com/humphrej/dhall-bazel/tree/master/examples/basic) without dhall-kubernetes using a simple bazel macro works ok.

I have made an example using dhall's dependency resolution to download dhall-kubernetes - see [here](https://github.com/humphrej/dhall-bazel/tree/master/examples/k8s_network_dependency).  This also works but is very slow (I think because dhall downloads each remote file separately), and introduces a network dependency to the bazel rule execution, which I would prefer to avoid.

My preferred approach is to use Bazel to download an archive release version of dhall-kubernetes, then have the rule access it locally (see [here](https://github.com/humphrej/dhall-bazel/tree/master/examples/k8s)). My solution requires a relative path in Prelude.dhall and package.dhall for the examples/k8s package to reference dhall-kubernetes.  While it works, I am concerned that this is subverting the Bazel sandbox by requiring special knowledge of the folder structure used internally by Bazel. Is there a better way?

Prelude.dhall:

```
../../external/dhall-kubernetes/1.17/Prelude.dhall
```

WORKSPACE:

```
workspace(name = "dhall")

load("@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/repo:http.bzl", "http_archive")

DHALL_KUBERNETES_VERSION = "4.0.0"

http_archive(
    name = "dhall-kubernetes",
    sha256 = "0bc2b5d2735ca60ae26d388640a4790bd945abf326da52f7f28a66159e56220d",
    url = "https://github.com/dhall-lang/dhall-kubernetes/archive/v%s.zip" % DHALL_KUBERNETES_VERSION,
    strip_prefix = "dhall-kubernetes-4.0.0",
    build_file = "@//:BUILD.dhall-kubernetes",
)
```

BUILD.dhall-kubernetes:

```
package(default_visibility=['//visibility:public'])

filegroup(
    name = "dhall-k8s-1.17",
    srcs = glob([
        "1.17/**/*",
    ]),
)
```

examples/k8s/BUILD:

```
package(default_visibility = ["//visibility:public"])

genrule(
    name = "special_ingress",
    srcs = ["ingress.dhall",
            "Prelude.dhall",
            "package.dhall",
        "@dhall-kubernetes//:dhall-k8s-1.17"
    ],
    outs = ["ingress.yaml"],
    cmd = "dhall-to-yaml --file $(location ingress.dhall) > $@",
    visibility = [
        "//visibility:public"
    ]
)
```

Comment: I took the suggestions in Gabriel Gonzalez's answer answer and updated my rules: https://github.com/humphrej/rules_dhall.  Advantages are that the bazel targets handle dependencies correctly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a way to instrument `dhall` to do "offline" builds, meaning that the package manager fetches all Dhall dependencies instead of Dhall fetching them.

In fact, I implemented something exactly this for Nixpkgs, which you may be able to translate to Bazel:

- [Add Nixpkgs support for Dhall](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/pull/79900)

### High-level explanation

The basic trick is to take advantage of a feature of Dhall's import system, which is that if a package protected by a semantic integrity check (i.e. a "semantic hash") is cached then Dhall will use the cache instead of fetching the package.  You can build upon this trick to have the package manager bypass Dhall's remote imports by injecting dependencies in this way.

You can find the Nix-related logic for this here:

- [Nix function for building a Dhall package](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/5c72e8416984879bd7bd884a392b7c915c28171a/pkgs/development/interpreters/dhall/build-dhall-package.nix)

... but I will try to explain how it works in a package-manager-independent way.

### Package structure

First, the final product of a Dhall "package" built using Nix is a directory with the following structure:

```
$ nix-build --attr 'dhallPackages.Prelude'         
…

$ tree -a ./result
./result
├── .cache
│   └── dhall
│       └── 122026b0ef498663d269e4dc6a82b0ee289ec565d683ef4c00d0ebdd25333a5a3c98
└── binary.dhall

2 directories, 2 files
```

The contents of this directory are:

- `./cache/dhall/1220XXX…XXX`

  A valid cache directory for Dhall containing a single build product: the binary encoding of the interpreted Dhall expression.

  You can create such a binary file using `dhall encode` and you can compute the file name by replacing the `XXX…XXX` above with the `sha256` encoding of the expression, which you can obtain using the `dhall hash` command.
- `./binary.dhall`

  A convenient Dhall file containing the expression `missing sha256:XXX…XXX`.  Interpreting this expression only succeeds if the expression we built matching the hash `sha256:XXX…XXX` is already cached.

  The file is called `binary.dhall` because this is the Dhall equivalent of a "binary" package distribution, meaning that the import can only be obtained from a binary cache and cannot be fetched and interpreted from source.
- Optional: `./source.dhall`

  This is a file containing a fully αβ-normalized expression equivalent to the expression that was cached.  By default, this should be omitted for all packages except perhaps the top-level package, since it contains the same expression that is stored inside of `./cache/1220XXX…XXX`, albeit less efficiently (since the binary encoding is more compact)

  This file is called `./source.dhall` because this is the Dhall equivalent of a "source" package distribution, which contains valid source code to produce the same result.

### User interface

The function for building a package takes four arguments:

- The package name

  This is not material to the build.  It's just to name things since every Nix package has to have a human-readable name.
- The dependencies for the build

  Each of these dependencies is a build product that produces a directory tree just like the one I described above (i.e. a `./cache` directory, a `./binary.dhall` file, and an optional `./source.dhall` file)
- A Dhall expression

  This is can be arbitrary Dhall source code, with only one caveat: all remote imports transitively referenced by the expression must be protected by integrity checks AND those imports must match one of the dependencies to this Dhall package (so that the import can be satisfied via the cache instead of the Dhall runtime fetching the URL)
- A boolean option specifying whether to keep the `./source.dhall` file, which is `False` by default

### Implementation

The way that the Dhall package builder works is:

- First, build the Haskell Dhall package with the `-f-with-http` flag

  This flag compiles out support for HTTP remote imports, that way if the user forgets to supply a dependency for a remote import they will get an error message saying `Import resolution is disabled`

  We'll be using this executable for all of the subsequent steps
- Create a cache directory within the current working directory named `.cache/dhall`

  ... and populate the cache directory with the binary files stored inside each dependency's `./cache/` directory
- Configure the interpreter to use the cache directory we created

  ... by setting `XDG_CACHE_HOME` to point to the `.cache` directory we just created in our current working directory
- Interpret and α-normalize the Dhall source code for our package

  ... using the `dhall --alpha` command.  Save the result to `$out/source.dhall` where `$out` is the directory that will store the final build product
- Obtain the expression's hash

  ... using the `dhall hash` command.  We will need this hash for the following two steps.
- Create the corresponding binary cache file

  ... using the `dhall encode` command and save the file to `$out/cache/dhall/1220${HASH}`
- Create the `./binary.dhall` file

  ... by just writing out a text file to `$out/binary.dhall` containing `missing sha256:${HASH}`
- Optional: Delete the `./source.dhall` file

  ... if the user did not request to keep the file.  Omitting this file by default helps conserve space within the package store by not storing the same expression twice (as both a binary file and source code).

### Packaging conventions

Once you have this function, there are a couple of conventions that can help simplify doing things "in the large"

- By default, a package should build a project's `./package.dhall` file
- Make it easy to override the package version
- Make it easy to override the file built within the package

  In other words, if a user prefers to import individual files like `https://prelude.dhall-lang.org/List/map` instead of the top-level `./package.dhall` file there should be a way for them to specify a dependency like `Prelude.override { file = "./List/map"; }` to obtain a package that builds and caches that individual file.

### Conclusion

I hope that helps!  If you have more questions about how to do this you can either ask them here or you can also discuss more on our Discourse forum, especially on the thread where this idiom first originated:

- [Dhall Discourse - Offline use of Prelude](https://discourse.dhall-lang.org/t/offline-use-of-prelude/137/12)

Comment: Thanks for such a complete explanation and it has certainly made me rethink the possible strategy.   I did a few tests and I see how the cache could be used as a dependency, so now I will cross check that with what can be done in bazel.

Comment: @user2515975: You're welcome!  Also, make sure to check out the linked Nixpkgs pull request because it also illustrates other details like how to bootstrap things.  For example, the Dhall package for the Prelude uses Nixpkg's support for fetching GitHub repositories instead of using Dhall to fetch things: https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/pull/79900/files#diff-8a0959c859b666be01254c5d2705801dR13-R21